# conceptualising motion in a vertical line

Tags: classical-mechanics

I'm having a tough time, fully understanding motion in vertical line. The thing that keeps confusing me is whether to use $-9.8 \ m/s^2 $ or $ 9.8 \ m/s^2$. I understand that the sign determines the direction we are moving in. So, if we describe an object moving upwards as a positive motion and an object going down as negative motion. Then does this imply when an object is going up acceleration will be $9.8 \ m/s^2$? I don't understand how this could be the case though, since if I threw a $10 \ kg $ dumbbell and a pen, I'm very sure the acceleration on the dumbbell would not be $9.8 \ m/s^2$.

Also could someone explain the following paragraph simply to me, especially the part which says Acceleration due to gravity is always downwards.

**When solving problems about vertical motion you can choose the positive direction to be either upwards or downwards. Acceleration due to gravity is always downwards, so if the positive direction is upwards then $a = -9.8 \ m/s^2$**

Comment: The sign indicates the direction of positive displacement, not the direction you are moving.

Comment: @ja72  
Does throwing an object upwards count as free fall? I mean an object being thrown upward at a velocity $v$, after 1 second, would have a velocity of v-9.81, after 2 seconds, v-2(9.81) and so on...

Comment: If an object is acted upon _only_ with gravity it is in free fall regardless if it going up or down. The moon is also in free fall around the earth, and so are all the satelites.

Answer (score 0):

Choose which direction you want to be positive. It doesn't matter which you choose initially. Everything else will depend on your choice. If you choose up to be positive, then gravity is pointing down, and the gravitational field will be g, downward, which means you should use a gravitational acceleration which points in the negative direction, $a_g=-9.80 \mathrm{m}/\mathrm{s}^2$ is you're on earth.

If you choose down to be positive, gravity is pointing in the positive direction and will produce a positive acceleration.  Objects moving upward will have negative velocities and decreasing position values.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to define the positive $\hat y$ direction from the start, irrespective of the motion..

First, choose a direction for your positive $\hat y$ - say the "up" direction.  For the motion of a particle going up the velocity is positive; for the motion of a particle going down, the velocity is negative.  With this convention, the acceleration is  $-9.8m/s^2$ since the acceleration vector is pointing downward, i.e. towards your 
negative $\hat y$.

If choose the direction of your positive $\hat y$ to be downwards, then  a particle going up would have negative velocity, a particle going down would have a positive velocity, and the acceleration would be $+9.8m/s^2$ since the acceleration vector is pointing downward, i.e. towards your 
positive $\hat y$.

Comment: Does throwing an object upwards count as free fall?

Comment: @eweewwrerdsd:    yes, as matter of fact.  Free fall occurs when the only force acting on an object is gravity.